# Error TF26212 in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have added a field "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate" in the work item TASK..where I selected the type as "date time control" and Rule as  "Required" now I exported the work itm and import the same for all projects.

now I am not able to Close any task. and shows an error tf26212 team foundation server can not save your changes , there may be problems with the work item type defination, try again or contact your team foundation server" i have an admin rights and i tried to change the rule as well as delete teh added field but still it is showing the same message. can any body help out?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're seeing this because you don't have a value in the field you marked as `Required`.  How are you setting this value?  From memory I think this is a field that might (by default) be automatically set in response to a state change but, if you're not setting that value, you might find you end up with an invalid work item.

Rather than deleting the added field, you could try removing the `Required` rule.

Comment: I have deleted the start date field now but still has a same issue just checked the XML file where i found two entries for closed date